# Do $2s$ and $2p$ orbitals have same energy?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, atomic-physics, orbitals, lamb-shift

While solving the Schrodinger equation for the H atom, we get $E_n$ depending exclusively on $n$ (actually on $\frac{1}{n^2}$). Then I thought 2s and 2p orbitals must have the same energy.

But while reading Molecular orbital theory in Atkin's Physical chemistry book, I found written that "$2s$ and $2p_z$ orbitals have distinctly different energies".

Can anyone please explain this?

Comment: The hydrogen 2s and 2p orbitals do not have the same energy. They are separated by the tiny Lamb shift, which is only 1057 MHz or 4.3714 10$^{-12}$ eV. The origin of this energy difference lies in radiative (QED) corrections to the degenerate Dirac result.

Comment: For hydrogen, the 2s and 2p states are energetically slightly different because of the Lamb shift.See http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/lamb.html for more

Comment: Atkins does not refer to the Lamb shift, but to the difference in energy between 2s and 2p in multielectron systems; which is the only place where we need molecular orbital theory.

Answer (score 1):

In a multielectron system by solving the Schrodinger equation you will see that the energy of the orbital doesnt only depend on n ,it depends on l as well.

Comment: The question is about the hydrogen atom, which is a single electron case. This does not address the question.

Comment: A molecule cant have 1 electron.

Answer (score 0):

The hydrogen 2s and 2p orbitals do not have the same energy. They are separated by the tiny Lamb shift, which is only 1057 MHz or 4.3714 10$^{−12}$ eV. The origin of this energy difference lies in radiative (QED) corrections to the degenerate Dirac result.

Note that there is also hyperfine splitting due to interaction with the proton spin. This is different for 2s and 2p.